# Why doesn't this SQL sub query statement work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The statement produces the following error.

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

I presume I somehow need to concatenate the field names in the subquery?

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COALESCE(Table_Field, Field) AS Fields
        FROM API_Objects_Fields
        WHERE Field IN (
                'fullname'
                ,'confirmed'
                ,'primary_email'
                ,'location_short'
                )
        )
FROM user_basics U
INNER JOIN Pod_Membership PM ON U.UserID = PM.UserID
WHERE PM.PodID = 164
ORDER BY U.Ctime DESC
```

The sub query specifies the fields to be returned from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT (
            SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 COALESCE(Table_Field, Field) 
            FROM API_Objects_Fields F
            WHERE F.UserID = PM.UserID AND F.Field IN (
                    'fullname'
                    ,'confirmed'
                    ,'primary_email'
                    ,'location_short'
                    )
            )AS Fields,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY Table_Field ORDER BY FIELD)AS RN
    FROM user_basics U
    INNER JOIN Pod_Membership PM ON U.UserID = PM.UserID
    WHERE PM.PodID = 164
    ORDER BY U.Ctime DESC
    )
    Select * from  CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

It is an assumption query basing on your question

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(Table_Field, Field) AS Fields
        FROM API_Objects_Fields
        WHERE Field IN (
                'fullname'
                ,'confirmed'
                ,'primary_email'
                ,'location_short'
                ) should return only 1 result, so refine where clause to return a unique record.

Comment: @akfkmupiwu please see above posted answer for your question

Comment: it will work if userid exists in API_Objects_Fields and it is unique

Comment: @akfkmupiwu for related query u posted in comment section  i have given solution in answer section for that one i am asking to see

Comment: yeah what you are saying it's right the tables should have relation then the subquery will works and what about the query you posted in comment section @akfkmupiwu

Comment: I am suggesting to @chris that subquery should return only 1 result, so refine where clause to return a unique record.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(1000)
    Select @Name = 
     COALESCE(@Name,'') +Table_Field + ';'  
FROM API_Objects_Fields
 WHERE Field IN 
( 'fullname' ,'confirmed' ,'primary_email' ,'location_short' )
    Select @Name As FieldName
```

@akfkmupiwu need to do like this for above comment

Comment: This will give same Field Name for all records. I am sure this is not his requirement, therefor he can refine where clause to return distinct or user JOIN as suggested by @Oğuz Sezer

Answer (score 0):

**What the error is telling you**

The problem with your query is exactly what the error says, it brings back more than one result. Since your subquery is in the select portion of the outer query (as opposed to the from or the where), sql is looking for the one value to populate the specific column. Think of it more in terms of filling in an excel spreadsheet. You cannot add two separate values to one cell. Instead, you need the data to go into two separate rows.

On another note, coalesce checks if the first value is null, if it is then it returns the second value. If the first value is not null, that value is returned. It sounds to me that this is not the behavior that you are looking for.

**How to fix this**

You need to either change your query to pull back different rows for each of the possible values that `Fields` can be or you need to find a way to specify only one value to return for `Fields`. Since I am unsure what you are looking for, I am going to demonstrate the first way of solving this.

**Data**

Your question does not provide any data for `API_Objects_Fields`, so I am going to make some up. Let's assume the columns in this table are `Field_ID`, `Table_Field`, and `Field` and let's say that your table looks like this:

> ```
>  Field_ID | Table_Field           | Field
>   1       |  Alan Turing          |  fullname
>   2       |  Catherine Zeta Jones |  fullname
>   3       |  True                 |  confirmed
>   4       |  MN                   |  location_short
>   5       |  123-456-7890         |  phone_number
> ```

As I mentioned before, right now your query would try to pull back the rows where the field is fullname, confirmed, or location_short all. Instead of trying to stuff one column of one row. full of 4 results, let's change your query to bring back 4 rows

**The Query**

```
SELECT f.Table_Field, Field
FROM user_basics U
INNER JOIN Pod_Membership PM ON U.UserID = PM.UserID
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Table_Field, Field
        FROM API_Objects_Fields
        WHERE Field IN (
                'fullname'
                ,'confirmed'
                ,'primary_email'
                ,'location_short'
                )
        ) f
WHERE PM.PodID = 164
ORDER BY U.Ctime DESC
```

**What will happen**

This query will now pull back data that looks more like this:

> ```
> Table_Field           | Fields
>  Alan Turing          |  fullname
>  Catherine Zeta Jones |  fullname
>  True                 |  confirmed
>  MN                   |  location_short
> ```

However, I think you will be surprised with the results you actually end up with. Since the query does not connect the data in API_Objects_Fields with any other tables, you would get the values from the results table above over and over again. In fact, you would get the values above for every single row returned by

```
Select *
From user_basics u
INNER JOIN Pod_Membership PM ON U.UserID = PM.UserID
WHERE PM.PodID = 164
```

If this query returns 12 results, you would end up with 12 Alan Turings, 12 Catherine Zeta Jones, 12 Trues, and 12 MNs. If this is not the result you are looking for, you will need to add an `ON` portion to the inner join so the results from `f` are connected with the other tables.